# How to resolve error with daterange in psql function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a psql function as given below :

```
create or replace function close_issue(issue varchar(128), device bigint, issue_daterange daterange) returns integer as $$
 declare curr_daterange daterange;

 begin
        if lower_inf(issue_daterange) then
            raise exception 'Issue date % cannot have lower bound infinity when closing issues', issue_daterange
                  USING HINT = 'issue_date should have a date range with interval, [date, date)';
       
        elsif upper_inf(issue_daterange) then
            raise exception 'Issue date % should not have upper bound infinity when closing issues', issue_daterange
                  USING HINT = 'issue_date should have a date range with interval, [date, date)';
        end if;
        
       if EXISTS(select * from issue_device_relation where issue_id = issue and device_id = device) then        
        select distinct on (occurrence_id) occurrence_id, issue_date into curr_daterange from issue_device_relation where issue_id = issue and 
            device_id = device order by occurrence_id desc;
        
            raise notice 'date range %', curr_daterange;
        
            if not (lower_inf(curr_daterange) and upper_inf(curr_daterange)) then --closed interval
                raise notice 'issue_id % on device_id % is already closed', issue, device;
                return 1;
        
            elsif not (issue_daterange <@ curr_daterange) then -- issue cannot be closed in history 
                raise notice 'issue_id % cannot be closed on device_id % with historical date range %', issue, device, issue_daterange;
                return 2;
        
            else
                raise notice 'issue is closed.'; --update date range here 
                return 3;
            end if;
      else
       raise notice 'issue id and device id not found';
       return 4;
      end if;
 end;
 $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY definer;
```

When I call the above function using the following query:

```
 select close_issue('test_issue', 12345, daterange('2020-09-01'::date, '2020-10-01'::date, '[)'))
```

It gives me the following error:

SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed range literal: "1"
Detail: Missing left parenthesis or bracket.

I have a hunch that it may be due to date range but can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: It would be nice to include the line number for the error. I suspect it is coming from `select distinct on (occurrence_id) occurrence_id, issue_date into curr_daterange` . `current_daterange` is declared as a daterange and the `select into` is trying to force an `occurrence_id`(guessing 1) into it. That `select into` would fail even if both values where dates anyway. You would need to  pass them to `current_daterange` as a `daterange`.

Comment: I just need to pass issue_date into curr_daterange not the occurrence. id

Comment: First, is `issue_date` a `daterange`? If not it will need to be made one before it can be assigned to `curr_daterange`. Second, `select distinct on (occurrence_id) occurrence_id, issue_date into curr_daterange` will not work as you are trying to assign two columns to one variable. For more information see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Comment: issue_date is a datarange, what I am trying to achieve is to get issue_date of max occurencce. yeah it seems is assigning two columns to one variable.

Comment: Then get rid of `occurrence_id` from returned fields. Also you are not getting `max` occurrence. You are getting `distinct on(occurrence_id)`. That may result in multiple `occurrence_id`s being returned if they are distinct from each other.

Comment: I have order by clause so it would order by occurrence_id in descending. order and would return first result.

Comment: Alright I misread. I thought you where after `max(issue_date)` for an `occurrence_id`.